# Laravel fichero de string para html

Tags: php, laravel, reactjs

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web con laravel.

Y tengo una duda de si es posible almacenar todas las cadenas que se van a utilizar en las etiquetas html en un solo archivo para llamarlas luego y así no repetir información. Sería algo parecido en java con los archivos properties.

muchas gracias

Comment: Esta pregunta esta basada en opiniones. En el tiempo que he usado Laravel, una forma de hacer esto es crear un archivo `constants.php` dentro de la carpeta `config`.

Comment: Para eso está  la  localización  https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/localization